Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' using better-sqlite3 in NextJs
I am trying to build a web3 project
I used wagmi to create a new project. This has nextjs included.
Now i wanted to use a database with my nextjs so i installed better-sqlite3
This is my code for the database
const sql = require("better-sqlite3");
const db = sql("pools.db");

const dummyPools = [
  {
    name: "USDC/WETH",
    slug: "usdc-weth",
    poolAddress:
      "0xd2b6214e0dfc2bc5cb2e4eb6bf3b3b4ab7b71f56bf550c1953d1d47c7647c832",
    token1Name: "USDC",
    token2Name: "WETH",
    token1Address: "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48",
    token2Address: "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
  },
];

db.prepare(
  `
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pools (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        slug TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        poolAddress TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        token1Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        token2Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        token1Address TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        token2Address TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
    )
    `
).run();

async function initData() {
  const stmt = db.prepare(`
        INSERT INTO pools VALUES (
            null,
            @slug,
            @name,
            @poolAddress,
            @token1Name,
            @token2Name,
            @token1Address,
            @token2Address
        )
        `);

  for (const pool of dummyPools) {
    stmt.run(pool);
  }
}

initData();


I ran the script and got the database. Then to use it in my components i created a lib folder in the root directory and  wrote this code
import sql from "better-sqlite3";

const db = sql("pools.db");

export function getPools() {
  return db.prepare("SELECT * FROM pools").all();
}


Then to fetch items from the data base i used the getPools in my component like this
import { getPools } from "../../../lib/pools";
import PoolsGrid from "./pools/pools-grid";

export default function HomePage() {
  const pools = getPools();
  return (
    <>
      <PoolsGrid pools={pools} />
    </>
  );
}

This file is in the app/components directory
And in the frontend i am getting this error
Failed to compile

../node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:2:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
../node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/index.js
./lib/pools.js
./src/app/components/home-page.tsx
./src/app/page.tsx


This is what the structure looks like
folder structure
I have a function createPool which creates a pool with two tokens. I want this data to be pushed to the database and then HomePage is gonna fetch and display. For now i have created a dummy data and want it to be displayed on the HomePage component

Is that getting bundled for the browser?

yes i guess since im using getPools() in a component

you can't do that

It started working now. I removed "use client" from the main page.tsx. Does that mean im not supposed to use "use client" anymore if i want the data to be fecthed from the database?

I figured you added 'use client' because the can't resolve module fs error is always a telltale sign of somebody trying to execute server side code in the client. It doesn't mean you can't ever use 'use client', it just means you need to be wary of where to use it. It is typically a bad idea to have it in page.tsx and layout.tsx because these files usually have other functions that help aggregate metadata and static params, and they have to run in the server. (1/2)

Next.js forces you to separate your components as much as possible. If you have a component that depends on hooks, it must be a client component, if this same component needs data from the server, it should probably receive it as props from a server component, or request it through a server action or an API route (though it's much better to just request it from the server directly and pass it through props). (2/2)
